# adding dates in php

Tags: php

I have the following statement. Either i get the date from the querystring or i get todays date.

I then need to get the current, previous, next month.

I think i'm going wrong by using "strtotime"

```
$selecteddate = ($_GET ['s'] == "" )
    ? getdate()
    : strtotime ($_GET ['s']) ;


    $previousMonth = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", $selecteddate) . " +1 month");

    $previousMonthName = $previousMonth[month];
    print $previousMonthName;
    $month = $selecteddate[month];
```

/* edit */

```
$selecteddate = ($_GET ['s'] == "" )
? getdate()
: strtotime ($_GET ['s']) ;

$previousMonth = strtotime(" -1 month", $selecteddate);
$nextMonth = strtotime(" +1 month", $selecteddate);


$previousMonthName = date("F",$previousMonth); //Jan
$nextMonthName = date("F",$nextMonth); // Jan
$month = $selecteddate[month];  // Aug
```

Comment: re. your edit; the `$selecteddate` will either hold an array (returned from `getdate()`) or an integer (returned from `strtotime()`). The later calls to `strtotime()` will not be happy at all if passed the array.

Answer (score 2):

you're almost right - just replace

```
$previousMonth = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", $selecteddate) . " +1 month");
```

by

```
$previousMonth = strtotime(" +1 month", $selecteddate);
```

take a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to learn more about the second parameter (called "$now"). to get the month names, do this ([documentation again](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)):

```
$previousMonthName = date("F",$previousMont);
$month = date("F",$selecteddate); // not sure if you want to get the monthname here,
                                  // but you can use date() to get a lot of other
                                  // values, too
```

Comment: wait i spoke to soon, see above. Is it returning Jan because it is not passing correctly?

Comment: and if you are using 5.3 you might want to check out [dateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) and then you can use the format `$nextMonth->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));`

Comment: Using `+1 month` (or its `P1M` friend) for this task is asking for trouble when adjacent months are shorter than the current/target month.

Answer (score 1):

[oezi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070426/adding-dates-in-php/7070461#7070461) will run into problems toward the end of some months.  This is due to PHP's interpretation of `±1 month` which simply increments/decrements the month, then adjusts the day part as appropriate.

For example, given `31 October` and `+1 month` the date will become `31 November` which does not exist. PHP takes that into account and roles the date around to `1 December`. The same would happen for `-1 month` to become `1 October`.

Various alternative approaches exist, one of which is to set modify the date explicitly with  (the little used) [`DateTime::setDate()`](http://php.net/datetime.setdate) as appropriate.

```
// e.g. $selecteddate = time();

$now = new DateTime;
$now->setTimestamp($selecteddate);

// Clone now to hold previous/next months
$prev = clone $now;
$next = clone $now;

// Alter objects to point to previous/next month
$prev->setDate($now->format('Y'), $now->format('m') - 1, $now->format('d'));
$next->setDate($now->format('Y'), $now->format('m') + 1, $now->format('d'));

// Go wild
var_dump($prev->format('r'), $next->format('r'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think salathe's answer might actually fall over the same problem he pointed out in oezi's answer. He passed $now->format('d') to setDate() as the day number but in a month with 31 days that might not make sense if the target month only has 30 days. I'm not sure what SetDate will do if you try to set a date that isn't sane - most likely throw an error. But the solution is very simple. All months have a day number 1. Here's my version of salathe's code.

```
// e.g. $selecteddate = time();

$now = new DateTime;
$now->setTimestamp($selecteddate);

// Clone now to hold previous/next months
$prev = clone $now;
$next = clone $now;

// Alter objects to point to previous/next month. 
// Use day number 1 because all the questioner wanted was the month.
$prev->setDate($now->format('Y'), $now->format('m') - 1, 1);
$next->setDate($now->format('Y'), $now->format('m') + 1, 1);

// Go wild
var_dump($prev->format('r'), $next->format('r'));
```